# lotus notes issue with UNID

Tags: lotus-notes

I exported data from the view. When I copy the exported UNID and search in lotus notes it shows like the UNID not found. But I retrieved the data from the same view. Please help me to solve this strange issue.

please find an image below

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you searched for the UNID in FullText search field. This might not work.

Go to your view and select menu Edit/Find/Replace (Ctrl+F). Enter the UNID and the according document will be found.

There is a shorter way if your view is sorted by UNID. Copy UNID into clipboard, open the view, click on a row and paste the content of the clipboard. It opens the "Find" dialog box directly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried all the possibilities like ctrl+f, indexing search. But it doesn't work. Please advise

Comment: Which way did you export your view?

Comment: Using lotus script agent.

Comment: Please post an image of your view. IMHO we don't have all the info we need to give you a correct answer.

Comment: @D.Bugger i have attached the image. from this view only i exported the Documents, if i search some other UNID it will show the corresponding document but this happens for some of the UNID. please help me to resolve this. - thanks.

Comment: Can you see the UNID in your view scrolling down the view?

Comment: Thanks. You could sort the view by UNID to quickly find the document. Does the SELECT for this view include the document you're looking for (agreeing with Knut)? And the document hasn't been removed, or archived?

Comment: i sorted the view and tried to find the UNID but same issue, the document has not deleted or archived.

Comment: actually i found that, i used to search UNID in the view called "all document by UNID" which contains all the document UNID's. in that view the total no. of documents present is around 300 but i used to export only one of the form named "frmPPR". when i open the view corresponding to frmPPR form it has around 1000 documents how the all document UNID have only 300 document overall and for the frmPPR view has 1000 documents? when searching in frmPPR  corresponding view i'm able to get the UNID. bit confused with this please advise.

Comment: Ah. Each view has a SELECT statement that tells Notes which documents should be shown in the view. Documents that do not match the SELECT are skipped. Compare the SELECT conditions in both views.

Comment: For "all document by UNID" view, the view selection formula is "SELECT @All", in frmPPR view the view selection formula is "Select (Form="frmPPR"). My doubt is in all document by UNID view we selected all the documents but it shows only 300 documents. why this happens

Comment: Just a check: open the Database Properties dialog box, the 2nd tab (i), how many documents are there really in the database? There are some options in a view that can change the number of documents in the view, like if the view is hierarchical or not (document-response hierarchy), but an All Documents view should normally show all documents. Maybe the view is corrupt. To test this, two options: 1/ make a completely new view, use Select @ALL, and check the number of documents, and 2/ type Ctrl-Shift-F9 and rebuild all views (or use Shift-F9 to rebuild the current view). PS: try Ctrl-Shift-L...